# What's wrong with this iterative deepening search code?(python)

Tags: python, search, recursion, graph, iteration

I implemented this into the project(Pacman), but it just doesn't move at all, it seems it enters an infinite loop or something....can someone tell me what's wrong with it??? I have been stuck here for several days.....

```
def depthLimitedSearch(problem, limit ):

    explored = set()                                         
    node = problem.getStartState()
    path = []

    def recursive_DLS(node, problem, limit, path):

        if node not in explored :    
            explored.add(node)      
            if problem.goalTest(node):      
                return path     
            elif limit == 0 :       
                return 'cutoff'
            else:            
                cutoff_occurred = False
                for successor in problem.getActions(node):   
                    child = problem.getResult(node,successor) #next state
                    result = recursive_DLS(child ,problem, limit - 1, path)  
                    if result == 'cutoff':
                    cutoff_occurred = True
                    elif result != None:
                    path.append(successor)
                if cutoff_occurred:
                    return 'cutoff'
                else:
                    return None

    return recursive_DLS(node, problem, limit, path)    


def iterativeDeepeningSearch(problem):

    for depth in xrange(sys.maxint):
        result = depthLimitedSearch(problem, 1)
        if result is not 'cutoff':
            return result
```

Comment: Could you give example input and outcome?

Comment: it's quite abstract.. problem refers to a specific problem and outcome should be a list of actions

Comment: Basically, it's much easier to figure out what's wrong if you give an example we can **actually run**, and see what's happening. Presumably you have such a thing, or you wouldn't know it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You are always passing a limit of `1` to `depthLimitedSearch`:

```
for depth in xrange(sys.maxint):
    result = depthLimitedSearch(problem, 1)
```

The `depth` is not used. If the search with limit 1 leads to a cutoff, this will iterate for a very long time without producing a result.

Comment: But here comes another problem...successor here refers to an action here, but when I run the program, the Pacman just doesn't move and instead, the color refers to the road changes... How it comes like this?.....